# SQLAlchemy select from one table using another table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE report_product (
  country VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  date_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  how_many INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY(country, date_time, product_id)
);
ALTER TABLE report_product
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_report_product_product
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) 
    REFERENCES product (id);
```

The point is, I want to `SELECT` from `report_product` the whole row, but having only product name. Is it OK to first find a product: `db.session().query(Product).filter(Product.name == name).first()` and then get its id, and then make another query to find specific `report`? Or I can do it easier?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter through relationship:
`db.session().query(ReportProduct).join(ReportProduct.product).filter(Product.name == name).first()`

See the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.join)